# Limit of quotient of factorial and ceiling

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am trying to study some calculus but I am faced with a problem. I need to compute $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x!}{(\lceil x \rceil)}$$ I have tried to use $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x!}{(\lceil x \rceil)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (2)(1)}{(\lceil x \rceil)}$$ but I cant see how to proceed. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this a limit of the sequence, where $x$ is indexed by $\Bbb Z_+$, or the limit of a function, where we define, say, $x! = \Gamma(x + 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer was posted for the unedited question stating $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x!}{\lceil x \rceil}$

If you compute the Right hand limit (R.H.L.), you will see that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x!}{\lceil x \rceil}$$ $$=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x!}{1}$$ since $\lceil x \rceil=1$ $$=\lim_{x \to 0^+} x! =\lim_{x \to 0^+} Γ(x+1) = 1 $$

But in case of Left hand limit (L.H.L.), you will see that $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{x!}{\lceil x \rceil}$$ does not exist because $\lceil x \rceil=0$ and the L.H.L. being undefined, the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x!}{\lceil x \rceil}$$ as such does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I made an err, it was $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I have edited it now

Comment: @gammatester Thanks for correcting...